# Where to implement isEditable, isSelectable in Xcode 4.3?

Tags: ios, textview, ios5, xcode-storyboard

I am using Xcode 4.3.2 and am new to app dev, I am using a storyboard to make a view etc and am using the textView View to have some text in it. Can someone tell me where and how I would implement the isEditable/isSelectable functions?

Answer (score 0):

You edit in the section on the right, after selecting the text box, you might need to scroll down/up in order to find it
This section would be over the tab where you got the original textbox from, make sure it is in the Text View tab

Comment: This is not what I was talking about. When you launch the app, and you hover over the text in the textview, I can type and distort the text. I only want to have the ability for the user to select it. If anyone knows how to do this please let me know.